# Does Defragmenting really help?

Tags: windows, defragment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is defragging relevant to improving disk performance anymore?](https://superuser.com/questions/4091/is-defragging-relevant-to-improving-disk-performance-anymore)

It used to be that defragmenting a hard drive gave a significant boost to performance. In the DOS days I would even defragment floppies if I wasn't going to make more changes to the files (it took a LONG time, but was well worth it).

Now... I don't know anymore. I know the theory, but over the last few years I've had a "fuzzy feeling" that not only it doesn't seem to help, but things actually get slower after the first defragmentation of a "virgin" hard drive. I'm not talking about flash drives -- I'm talking good old-fashioned hard drives.

Also, I've used third party tools that are able to defragment more files (MBR on boot, etc) or have more fancy features, and I don't know that it makes a difference in performance either. They run prettier, sure, but that's not enough for my pocket.

I don't know if I'm dreaming it. Is there any hard data on this? Does defragment still help in modern Windows?

My experience has been 99% on Windows XP. How about Vista or Windows 7? Is defragmentation more effective in those versions of Windows?

Comment: Yes

Comment: I'm always tempted to just answer "Yes" or "No" for questions where the title is closed ended.

Comment: @Grant: I believe in "short and sweet" subjects; they are 'summaries'. The question body has a few ideas and thoughts, and more detailed inquiries -- I count three question marks in the body :-). Obviously I'm not after a veredict but a discussion on the topic. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Defragmenting in general will have little perceptible effect unless the filesystem is *very* fragmented to start with (i.e. has been around some time and seen a lot of activity, or has become very full (>85%) at some point). Modern filesystems like ext2/3/4 and NTFS are pretty good at avoiding chronic fragmentation.

There are a few exceptions to this rule:

1. FAT16/FAT32 filesystems use a beginning-to-end first-fit block allocation algorithm when creating and growing files which leads to very bad fragmentation in many cases
2. Some defragmenters will do a good job of arranging related files together, specifically those used at boot time. This can improve boot speed though won't improve a lot much else. Later Windows variants do this to a certain extent automatically, so it does not need to be done manually
3. Back when Windows would start with a FAT filesystem then convert to NTFS during the install process running a defragment after install had completed could make a measurable difference. Some suggest this (defragmenting after install is a useful task) is still the case, many suggest otherwise.

Also not that if you are talking about a filesystem that will be used by multiple users at the same time, or just multiple applications depending on the I/O load the impart, defragmenting makes little difference (unless the filesystem was in a *very* messy state to start with) as your drive heads will be flipping back and forth anyway to serve the different concurrent tasks.

Answer (score 7):

Special Note: Do not defrag Solid State Drives. The extra passes are unnecessary and will shorten the lifetime of your drive.

Comment: From what I've read (I've not seen it firsthand), SSD's won't even allow you to defrag. It's like, grayed out it Windows or something.

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting information in [Measuring Performance in Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/Vista_perf.mspx) ...

> Disk defragmentation moves fragmented
>   files to larger contiguous regions on
>   the disk. It moves files accessed at
>   boot and application startup toward
>   the outer edge of the disk, where
>   higher transfer rates can be achieved.
>   Disk defragmentation also uses
>   low-priority I/O.

It seems it would not only help reduce seek and spin times, but also increase data transfer rates for boot files (decrease boot time).