# How to move files to high speed area of the disk?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a Samsung SSD as primary and Seagate barracuda 1TB HDD as Secondary Disk drives on my system.

Initially the read write rate of the HDD was pretty fast (100MBps and greater) but over time  (few months)  the speed read write for newer files have degraded to less than 10MBps with just 9% fragmentation. If I check the resource monitor nothing seems to be using the disk other than the program I am running.

I believe this is due to the physical structure of disk i.e head has to travel more when files are near centre of the platter than on the edge.

Regardless is there a way to identify areas of disk that are accessible faster and then move the frequently used files there?

EDIT: This is different question than defragmentation because I want to be able to select by myself which files and folders get to be in High speed area of the disk

I also suspect that maybe this disk is optimised for backups and not efficient for realtime use after first few Gigs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Defragmenting really help?](http://superuser.com/questions/23940/does-defragmenting-really-help), [Is defragging relevant to improving disk performance anymore?](http://superuser.com/questions/4091/is-defragging-relevant-to-improving-disk-performance-anymore/5013).

Comment: Also see: [Are partitions to the inner/outer edge significantly faster](http://superuser.com/questions/643013/are-partitions-to-the-inner-outer-edge-significantly-faster)

Comment: The link in Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's second comment explains why what you want to do won't make a difference, so it might obviate your need for an answer.  However, it doesn't actually answer your question.  Please indicate whether you're still looking for an answer on how to do it.