# Windows 7 very slow on loading programs or accessing files

Tags: windows-7, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Machine! What can I check?](https://superuser.com/questions/26862/slow-machine-what-can-i-check)

For the last couple of days, I start having some problem with Windows 7.
I do development, with VS 2008 / Sql Server 2008, and in the last couple of days (or maybe a week or two - I cannot tell for sure) I noticed Windows is getting very slow on some things.
For example, when my testing code runs a query, or when I try to start VS 2008. First I noticed during running queries from code (the DB is about 2 GB with over 1 million records). But the same db works very fast on production server (Windows server 2003). Then I noticed it's not about db only, but might be related with Windows itself. For example, when I try to launch various programs (VS 2008, or ssms), after I click the icon, sometime it starts instantly, and sometimes could take up to 1-2 min till Windows seems to react. 
I installed SP1 few days ago and I'm wondering if that could be the cause? I'm affarid to not be the HDD (although it didn't exhibitany signs of problems, like odd sound or such).

I optimized the HDD with UltraDefrag, hoping for some improvements, but still after, it took me more then 2 min to start VS 2008 (since I click its icon to the moment ir asked for admin permission - it is set to run in admin mode).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does UltraDefrag run all the time?  Have seen this cause real system slowdowns.  Never discovered why but removing improved performance.

Do you have an AV program running.  Is it set to scan on access?  Some are very agressive and all the scanning slows things down?

Any chance you have some malware that is resulting in slow performance?

Have you run any monitoring to possibly identify a process that is impacting performance? Task Manager would be a place to start.  Opne TaskManager and then try Visual Studio.