# Laptop running super slow all of a sudden?

Tags: windows-7, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the first steps for diagnosing a slow machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/26862/what-are-the-first-steps-for-diagnosing-a-slow-machine)

Can anyone help, my laptop has started running very slow! things take forever to open, especially outlook and internet explorer. however its generally slow all around. i have run many spyware and malware scans and all were clean. i have tried disabling certain startup software, but still isnt helping that much!

Any thoughts, and help would be killer!

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, and can have multiple reasons for the slow response.

My first thought, in the past I have some bad experiences with Windows 7, after installing SP1 on some machines (not all) everything feels "slow", could this be happening to you ?

In that case, the only solution I can come up until now is reinstall the O.S.