# Windows 7 X64 Professional Randomly Freezing On New PC

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have recently purchased a brand new custom built high-specification PC with Windows 7 x64 Professional.

I am regularly encountering freezing problems whereby the computer becomes totally unresponsive and I forced to cut power to the device and restart it.

I have followed the information as recommended at [How do I troubleshoot a Windows freeze or slowness?](https://superuser.com/questions/26862/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness) but I am still encountering problems.

Can anyone please explain as how I should proceed further?

Comment: Thanks for your response @BramVanroy. So far I've tried sfcscan, chkdsk, and updated all drivers. I'm currently running Memtest and reading into if it could be a poorly configured BIOS.

Comment: Any error messages or items in Event Viewer which would give you a clue what is going on?

Comment: hanks for your response @CharlieRB. The following item is the only item I have found in the EventViewer whose time correlates to the last system freeze - "Session "Microsoft Security Client OOBE" stopped due to the following error: 0xC000000D"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things causing your problem. The error you mentioned refers to Microsoft Security Essentials. If you are using it, or if it was uninstalled, it can be causing issues.

From the event error you commented above, you can try the following to see if it resolves the issue - [Microsoft Security Client OOBE stopped due to the following error: 0xC000000D](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprosecurity/thread/0c942bd9-47ad-4897-a5c2-485cc9fe681f/)

Comment: Thanks @CharlieRB. I stumbled across this page myself and deleted the file in question and so far so good. I've also downgraded the speed on my RAM as a precaution (sorry for my lack of proper technology terminiology). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

press the CAPS LOCK key when you have the issue again.

When you do this, if the CAPS LOCK light on the keyboard does not change when you press the CAPS LOCK key, the computer may be completely unresponsive (hard hang).

This scenario usually indicates a problem with the hardware. Or, the driver can cause this problem. To help isolate the problem, check the following items:

```
Overclocking: Disable overclocking to see whether the issue occurs when the system is run at the correct speed.

Check the memory: Verify the memory by using a memory checker. Verify that each memory chip is the same speed and that it is configured correctly in the system.

Power supply: Make sure that the power supply has enough wattage to appropriately handle the installed devices. If you added memory, installed a newer processor, installed additional drives, or added external devices, such devices can require more energy than the current power supply can provide consistently.

Overheating: Check whether the system is overheating by examining the internal temperature of the hardware.

Defaults: Use system defaults, and run the system.
```

If the light doesn't toggle, it is a software that freezes the PC.

Source:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en#method3

Comment: Thanks magicandre1981. Just prior to your reply I lowered the clock speed and also followed @CharlieRB's recommedations and at present my system is functioning well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this issue and it was driving me crazy. The mouse would keep pausing every few seconds and I couldn't understand why. No spyware or viruses.

It turned out to be nothing more than nvidia drivers installed by windows 7 updates. I just downloaded the official 'full package' drivers (about 170mb) from the nvidia website and voila, no problem. How on earth I found this out is pure fluke. I also found out that simply putting the sata lead in the wrong port on your motherboard can cause issues such as trying to run a sata III /6gb drive on an incorrect 3gb port instead. So check your manual as it is easily done.

Even if you don't have an nvidia graphics card/system it could be drivers provided by microsaft update service. Go through the drivers for your pc that have been updated. Try uninstalling them and install official drivers. Microsofts drivers can really cause more issues than they fix and are not always up to date/complete.

Good luck and hope ive helped a little.