# Analyzing Windows 7 intermittent freezes

Tags: windows-7, performance, freeze, troubleshooting

For a few weeks now, my Windows 7 installation has been showing intermittent freezes. Typically, the currently focused application window will freeze for up to 7 seconds, but I can still switch to a different application which will be working fine. Often, Firefox will freeze when loading a page, but other applications freeze as well at unpredictable times.

I created two xperf traces which capture a freeze in two different applications, as well as a trace without a freeze (following [Tom Wijsman's instructions](https://superuser.com/a/205307/319621)). The only correlation I found so far is some higher-than-usual writing to the disk occurring near the moment of the freeze, but in the summary table, I see no obvious differences between the freezing and the non-freezing traces. What should I be looking for?