# How can I fix the massive keyboard lag I get in some scenarios

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, keyboard, start-menu

I get major delays in some scenarios using my keyboard and sometimes also mouse. Using (browser-like?) apps e.g. Windows start menu, Firefox, Chrome in Windows 10, it can take seconds or minutes for what I type to appear on screen (including this question!). Typing a lot of characters usually results in a few being displayed before a long delay, then all the remaining characters typed are spat out. Sometimes the problem is not apparent at startup, but almost inevitably develops at some point and then does not resolve without a reboot. Usually it does not affect performance in other programs e.g. Ms Word. This isn't a new issue.

I've recorded an example using Windows Performance Recorder https://www.dropbox.com/s/cr05fvvi0cp0q0s/TOMPC.03-21-2018.12-44-41.zip?dl=0

Having tried to look at the analysis and previously looking at task manager I've wondered whether Cortana is somehow involved. I tried disabling it through the registry but I think that's the communication with microsoft and anyway it didn't help.

System is:

- Windows 10 Home 1709 16299.309
- Intel i5-2500K
- Asus PBZ77-V LX
- USB wired keyboard (I've also used a different wireless keyboard)

Hard drive SMART info from HDTune:

```
HD Tune: Corsair Force 3 SSD Health

ID                               Current  Worst    ThresholdData       Status   
(01) Raw Read Error Rate         90       90       50       223712322  Ok       
(05) Reallocated Sector Count    100      100      3        0          Ok       
(09) Power On Hours Count        85       85       0        13512      Ok       
(0C) Power Cycle Count           100      100      0        984        Ok       
(AB) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        0          Ok       
(AC) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        0          Ok       
(AE) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        96         Ok       
(B1) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        4          Ok       
(B5) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        0          Ok       
(B6) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        0          Ok       
(BB) (unknown attribute)         100      100      0        0          Ok       
(C2) Temperature                 30       30       0        1966110    Ok       
(C3) Hardware ECC Recovered      120      120      0        223712322  Ok       
(C4) Reallocated Event Count     100      100      3        0          Ok       
(C9) TA Counter Detected         120      120      0        223712322  Ok       
(CC) Soft ECC Correction         120      120      0        223712322  Ok       
(E6) GMR Head Amplitude          100      100      0        100        Ok       
(E7) Temperature                 100      100      10       0          Ok       
(E9) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        8192       Ok       
(EA) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        6458       Ok       
(F1) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        6458       Ok       
(F2) (unknown attribute)         0        0        0        12056      Ok       

Power On Time         : 13512
Health Status         : Ok

HD Tune: WDC     WD2003FZEX-00Z4S Health

ID                               Current  Worst    ThresholdData     Status   
(01) Raw Read Error Rate         200      200      51       0        Ok       
(03) Spin Up Time                145      137      21       11708    Ok       
(04) Start/Stop Count            98       98       0        2832     Ok       
(05) Reallocated Sector Count    200      200      140      0        Ok       
(07) Seek Error Rate             200      200      0        0        Ok       
(09) Power On Hours Count        89       89       0        8653     Ok       
(0A) Spin Retry Count            100      100      0        0        Ok       
(0B) Calibration Retry Count     100      100      0        0        Ok       
(0C) Power Cycle Count           100      100      0        435      Ok       
(C0) Power Off Retract Count     200      200      0        73       Ok       
(C1) Load Cycle Count            200      200      0        2758     Ok       
(C2) Temperature                 113      102      0        39       Ok       
(C4) Reallocated Event Count     200      200      0        0        Ok       
(C5) Current Pending Sector      200      200      0        0        Ok       
(C6) Offline Uncorrectable       200      200      0        0        Ok       
(C7) Ultra DMA CRC Error Count   200      200      0        0        Ok       
(C8) Write Error Rate            200      200      0        0        Ok       

Power On Time         : 8653
Health Status         : Ok
```

Comment: are you using wireless keyboard / mouse ?

Comment: Could be a hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: It's a hard-wired USB keyboard.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks. Both hard drives report ok health status. Details added to post.

Comment: Installed Windows Performance Analyzer. (You must first install WPA as a part of the ADK KIT, from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install and choose which other 8 GB of other tools you want.  The WPR - Performance Recorder itself, is also quite large).  I got your 2 GB file -- and that is ONLY a 10 minutes recording??  Great exercise, but I didn't see anything obvious, but will need to become more familiar with the tool again, (since XP days). Any WPA experts out there?

Comment: Thanks for looking @DaaBoss I may have selected more options in WPR than needed and maybe not others that would have been useful.

Comment: I think @Tom-Wijsman is a WPA expert https://superuser.com/a/205307/885974

Comment: if u have a ps2 port try you could try that ;-)   (that was the solution to a slow usb keyboard back in the day)

Comment: Thanks @barlop I can't find my ps/2 adapter so I've ordered one. I don't think it's that as I don't have the problems in other applications but just in case.

Comment: @TomCrocker  oh I don't think that be faster.. cos an adaptor goes through usb to your application, so whatever issue there is on that 'journey' would likely be inherited.

Comment: @barlop Not sure if you realise I mean a USB to ps2 (i.e. to plug USB keyboard into ps2 port on motherboard). Agree it's unlikely to fix it and don't even know if the ps2 port is essentially a ps2 to USB adapter (it's a shared mouse or keyboard port). Anyway, worth a try for £3

Comment: @TomCrocker oh that's brilliant that you have ps2 ports. You could even try a ps2 keyboard. They are so responsive they even flash as soon as the computer turns on.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 10 and I noticed when I switched from Edge to Chrome the lag went away. My keyboard lag was experienced when using email. I also use Linux on a different computer. I use Firefox and access the same mail box with no lag problems.