# Does TrueCrypt offer error correction or file redundancy?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt

I am interested in using OS encryption when I reformat my PC soon. I am afraid of transfer errors and what happens if the disk is not dismounted properly (such as BSOD or other crash, or physically removing a device like a flash drive without dismounting the volume).

Does TrueCrypt or other encryption software like Bitlocker account for errors? Is there a redundancy setting?

I have a Samsung Evo 840 SSD I'm going to be using.

Comment: Your question is likely to get closed because you are basically trying to sneak two questions into a single question.  I believe the the later question about SSD an encryption has already been addressed here.  http://superuser.com/questions/448965/does-full-disk-encryption-on-ssd-drive-reduce-its-lifetime

Comment: I meant in reference to encryption process & SSD issues, not wear leveling but I removed it just in case. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does TrueCrypt or other encryption software like Bitlocker account for errors? Is there a redundancy setting?

This isn't really something that full disk encryption software should be doing.  It really isn't the right layer to be performing this type work.  It should either be lower a the device level (see most SANS), or higher at the filesystem level.

With most full disk encryption tools, you can backup your volume keys and headers so that you can recover the volume in the case of some kind of failure that results in the keys/headers being destroyed.

You should be doing error checking at a different layer.  For example you can layer a ReFS filesystem on top of a bitlocker encrypted drive, which will give you enhanced error checking.

You could just run perform proper backups on the system.  A good backup system should be able to identify and restore any corruption or errors.